# Is there a way of converting an image to HSL using Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Is there a way of converting an image to HSL with Pillow in Python?

Ideally I would like to be able to open a JPEG, convert it to HSL, change the HSL values, convert back to RGB and save.

The only way I can figure is using `colorsys.rgb_to_hls` on each pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pillow (5.4.1) does not support converting RGB to HSL:

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 27 2018, 07:35:52)
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.open("Tests/images/hopper.png")
>>> hsl = im.convert("HSL")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1030, in convert
    im = self.im.convert(mode, dither)
ValueError: conversion from RGB to HSL not supported
```

However, if you can work with it, RGB to HSV is supported:

```
from PIL import Image

print("Open a JPEG")
im = Image.open("Tests/images/hopper.png")
px = im.load()
print(im.mode)  # "RGB"
print(px[0, 0])  # (20, 21, 67) ~= navy

print("Convert it to HSV")
hsv = im.convert("HSV")
px = hsv.load()
print(hsv.mode)  # "HSV"
print(px[0, 0])  # (169, 178, 67) ~= navy

print("Change an HSV value")
px[0, 0] = (0, 255, 255)  # red
print(px[0, 0])  # (0, 255, 255) == red

print("Convert back to RGB and save")
im2 = hsv.convert("RGB")
px = im2.load()
print(im2.mode)  # "RGB"
print(px[0, 0])  # (255, 0, 0) == red
im2.save("out.png")
```