# Classifying images based on whether they are colour or non-colour

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb

I have a task where I need to detect whether documents (pdf/word) are in colour or not. As I don't have access to data I am working on the pretense that these documents will need to be converted to jpeg for processing.

The initial direction I was provided was to use a pre-trained image classification model but I felt this was overkill and have been investigating whether inspecting the image pixels instead, I assumed this would be a quicker and less compute intensive. My idea was to classify images as grayscale/bw and anything that did not meet this criteria would be considered colour.

From the articles I have read I understand a grayscale image is one that has a single channel or if it is 3 channel R==G==B for all pixels and produced code based off [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660929/how-to-check-whether-a-jpeg-image-is-color-or-gray-scale-using-only-python-stdli) however when inspecting my images at times images that the layman would consider as 'not colour' did not have equal R, G, B values. Example images can be seen below:

1. https://www.pexels.com/photo/monochrome-photo-of-high-rise-buildings-2539658/
2. https://unsplash.com/photos/--AS0fm7E88
3. https://unsplash.com/photos/I6Rlq3H_ca0
4. https://www.pexels.com/photo/grayscale-photo-of-building-2817869/

What I typically found for these cases was that the R would be around 10 away from G and B and G and B would be equal or very close thus implemented arbitrary tolerances for R-G and B-G of 10 and 3 respectively after inspecting the RGB values for some of these images, just looking at these colours they do still tend to be shades of grey. I feel my approach is not necessarily the most robust so was looking gain a better understanding of this scenario.

My questions are:

1. Is there a more robust way to deal with such cases other than hardcoded, arbitrary tolerance values or if this is a valid approach are there any articles, papers that could help me justify this?
2. Why is it that these images don't have R=G=B, I can understand slight noise (+/-3) but unsure why R is so much further away from G and B?

As explained I tried implementing code based on the linked article. Was expecting to see R=G=B for grayscale images but not always the case it seems.

Comment: How about transforming to HSV (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54970416/is-there-a-way-of-converting-an-image-to-hsl-using-pillow) and defining "non-colour" images as those where the S (Saturation) value doesn't exceed some threshold? (You might want to try a few different approaches - e.g. do you care about the average saturation, or the maximum, etc)

Comment: Are there any values that values of S that are typically used for classifying "non-colour" or grayscale images? The rule of using R==G==B for greyscale is why RGB seemed like a good choice and using the tolerances could account for the noise so that rule may still stand true (Idk for sure).

Also I had a play with some colour pickers but I don't believe fixing S alone would be sufficient as there are some shades of black with 100% saturation which may be neglected. Imagine it would have to be a series of ranges but would be good to know if there is a standard here too

Comment: Good question - I wouldn't call myself an expert on this, and ultimately it's somewhat subjective, but there's another answer here which is interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56571378/765091

Comment: Personally, I would do my very best to avoid JPEG when looking at colour. It does *"chroma subsampling"* which makes an almighty mess if you are looking at colour analysis.